# Why does my "Problems" panel tab handle disappear whenever I select a different panel tab in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

So my problems is not appearing on my VS Code. I can go in "view" and make it show up, but if I click in any of the other options on the terminal like debug, the tab handle for the problems panel tab will disappear again.

[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPkz8.png)
[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNB9J.png)

Why is this happening, and how can I get the problems panel tab handle to always show again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably changed it by accident to not be shown by default. If you right-click the tab bar of the panel UI element, you'll see each of the panel names that you can click to toggle whether they get shown by default (they get shown by default when toggled to have a checkmark beside their name in that right-click menu). You just need to toggle its name entry to have the checkmark in the panel's tab bar's right-click menu again.